# UserSecrets.dll not finding project.json

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm converting an aspnet5/rc-1 website to the released aspnet core. I'm running into a problem involving user secrets in the development environment.

The call to AddUserSecrets, in the Startup constructor, throws an exception:

```
public Startup( IHostingEnvironment env )
{
    // Set up configuration sources.
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile( "appsettings.json" )
        .AddJsonFile( $"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true );

    if( env.IsDevelopment() )
    {
        // this line blows up
        builder.AddUserSecrets();
    }

    builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
    Configuration = builder.Build();
```

The error message is something to the effect that the project.json file could not be found in the bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.0 folder...which is weird, because I wouldn't expect to find the project.json file in the distributable executable folder in the first place.

This all worked fine under rc1, so something has changed.

**Additional Info**

Here is the exception detail:

> System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
>   HResult=-2146233079   Message=Unable to locate a project.json at
>   'C:\Programming\SpeedView\src\SpeedView\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0\'.
>   Source=Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets   StackTrace:
>          at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets.PathHelper.GetSecretsPath(IFileProvider
>   provider)
>          at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationExtensions.AddUserSecrets(IConfigurationBuilder
>   configuration)
>          at SpeedView.Startup..ctor(IHostingEnvironment env) in C:\Programming\SpeedView\src\SpeedView\Startup.cs:line 48
>   InnerException:

Here is project.json file:

```
{
  "userSecretsId": "aspnet5-SpeedView-f526a1b2-f58b-4e04-b189-8442609eff8c",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "AutoMapper": "5.0.2",
    "Serilog.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",
    "Serilog.Sinks.ColoredConsole": "2.0.0",
    "Serilog.Sinks.Literate": "2.0.0",
    "Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile": "2.2.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
  },

  "tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.0.238",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "Areas/**/Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp siteprep" ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the actual exception message and your project.json file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget to set your BasePath:

```
public Startup( IHostingEnvironment env )
{
 // Set up configuration sources.
 var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath) // Add this line <-----
    .AddJsonFile( "appsettings.json" )
    .AddJsonFile( $"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true );
```

Comment: Thanx, Gerardo; that was the problem. Do you know where the reason behind this change is documented?

Comment: Here they decided to create the BasePath https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/issues/159
and here they removed it from the ConfigurationBuilder constructor https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/commit/bf62a69de10a50f01ddc4b9049abe8572c4995d8#diff-eaa00df041a94f159a5154d9a19a3910R17

Comment: Appreciate the links. Now I understand the change, to support decoupling.